# Website Branch address not updating in Google search engine even after 1 month

Tags: search, web-crawler

Adecco locations' working hours not getting update on Google:

For two locations of Adecco Belgium- Adecco Hoogstraten and ADECCO OOSTMALLE, the working hours are updated in sitecore  as following:

1. Adecco Hoogstraten- Tuesday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
   Thursday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
2. Adecco Hoogstraten- Monday9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
   Friday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM

Follwing details are updated on Google search

https://www.google.com/search?q=adecco+oostmalle&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN1087IN1087&oq=adecco+oostmalle&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCggAEAAY4wIYgAQyCggAEAAY4wIYgAQyDQgBEC4YrwEYxwEYgAQyCAgCEAAYFhgeMgoIAxAAGA8YFhgeMggIBBAAGBYYHjIICAUQABgWGB4yBggGEEUYPDIGCAcQRRg80gEINTE2MmowajeoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

below data need to be updated it is updated in the live site but not in Google.

1. Adecco Hoogstraten- Tuesday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
   Thursday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
2. Adecco Hoogstraten- Monday9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM
   Friday 9:00 Am to 12:00 PM and 2:00 AM to 5:00 PM